# Почему vue ломается или выводит предыдущее значение на v-if?

Tags: vue.js

Vue 2.6.10.

Компонент для отрисовки элемента списка. В него прокинут через v-bind данные в переменную item.

Внутри шаблона есть проверки, чтобы вывести разный текст\картинку в зависимости от значения. Но случаются две ситуации:

- либо компонент крашится и не выводит ничего (логов нет, т.к. vue подключается как скрипт в страницу, никаких бандлеров, режимов отладки, только хардкор)
- либо показывает предыдущее значение условия

Для первого случая применятся v-else-if, для второго просто третий v-else.
Выглядит это так:

```
<div v-if="item.option_term === 0">Сегодня</div>
<div v-else-if="item.option_term === 1">Завтра</div>
<div v-else><% if item.option_term  %></div>
```

Или так же, но без v-else-if.
Не понимаю почему так происходит, ведь v-else-if ввели еще в 2.1 версии.
В принципе, можно решить через data и методы, где прокидывать данные в метод, что-то порешать, подставить по-умолчанию значение и выплюнуть значение нужное. Но хочется просто на шаблоне и понять чего не так-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в html (там где v-else). Думаю по этому у Вас и не работает.

Вот корректный html:

```
<div v-if="item.option_term === 0">Сегодня</div>
<div v-else-if="item.option_term === 1">Завтра</div>
<div v-else>{{ item.option_term }}</div>
```

Comment: нет. <% if item.option_term  %> это делимитры выставленные мною из настроек. {{ }} и {% %} делимитры шаблонизатора dtl, который уже потом отдаст строку. vue их не увидит уже. но чтоб не путаться самим, для vue скармливаем другие делимитры.

Comment: а. вы поменяли делимитры, и удалили if внутри вывода. заметил. Да, вы правы, это то, что нужно